# Display Grails list attribute in jasper report

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, grails-plugin

I don't know how to render a list attribute from Grails in a jasper report

My domain class looks like this:

```
class Project {


String name
String division
List divisions

String toString(){
    "$name"
}


static hasMany = [divisions : Division ]
...
```

And the division domain class comes here

```
class Division {

String name
String divisionResponsible
String createDate

...
```

The project controller looks like this

```
class ProjectController {


def scaffold = true

def index = {
    redirect(action : list)
}


def createReport = {

    def projectreport = Project.getAll([params.project_id])
    chain(controller:'jasper',action:'index',model:[data:projectreport],params:params)

}
```

}

I created a jasper report with iReport, which works fine. I added the fields in the list and they show in the report by accessing e.g. $F{name}, but I have no idea how to add the divisions list. I want a list with one element per line.

**UPDATE** jrxml file added:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports  http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="books" language="groovy"  pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20"  topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="589a675d-513d-46ec-9006-3fa969e8706c">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="2.4793388429752063"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="193"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="397"/>
<style name="table">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<subDataset name="Table Dataset 1" uuid="b86e8ec3-65e5-4049-a20a-196817cb20f9"/>
<subDataset name="dataset1" uuid="92950e66-e6cf-4276-a35e-08a5874a7395"/>
<subDataset name="dataset2" uuid="8f6281e8-ec37-4c7a-896d-f70ffe464372"/>
<parameter name="id" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["<parameter error>"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<field name="internet" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="projectResponsible" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="criticality" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="notes" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="id" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="divisions" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="projectStatus" class="java.lang.String"/>
<group name="Group1">
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="33">
            <line>
                <reportElement uuid="79864a95-d697-467e-bc50-8ef45a45d907" x="-20" y="32" width="595" height="1" forecolor="#666666"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="32eb2454-9c31-4af7-b7d2-2f1500d0f0b9" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="12" width="124" height="20" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Project status]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="f4a48bf5-2347-48d8-90be-48ef1fc765d7" x="124" y="13" width="164" height="20" forecolor="#006699"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{projectStatus}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<group name="Group3">
    <groupFooter>
        <band/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<group name="Group4">
    <groupFooter>
        <band/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<background>
    <band/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="72">
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="d6921c84-754f-47f8-8e1c-ed5296807395" mode="Opaque" x="-20" y="-20" width="595" height="92" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="f9a14771-1465-4f54-ba47-0fa5297df8df" x="20" y="20" width="245" height="33" forecolor="#006699"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="24" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Project Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <image>
                <reportElement uuid="3de03b7e-39e1-4b64-bde9-0a663fea3cc6" x="279" y="16" width="306" height="76"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\Guest\\Desktop\\Logo.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </frame>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="13"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="21">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="f2fa74e2-9914-4bfa-872b-6afb705b016c" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="124" height="20" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Project]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <line>
            <reportElement uuid="c5c5d539-6b26-4467-befe-de4a4adc28fe" x="-20" y="20" width="595" height="1" forecolor="#666666"/>
        </line>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="ff2c3497-9ef4-4546-b1b0-d9e44f8944af" x="124" y="1" width="164" height="20" forecolor="#006699"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="194">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="eb8ac25a-7d64-41f8-9e72-04103fd7d9c1" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="23" width="124" height="20" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E3E3E3"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Project Resonsible]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="aee33b53-790c-4749-ba9e-b83a7752af74" mode="Opaque" x="124" y="23" width="164" height="20" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E3E3E3"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{projectResponsible}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="42af2015-ef1f-4f81-996f-238030838ad2" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="43" width="124" height="20" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Criticality]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="7cf09291-11fc-4cff-a7b4-a07722c8953b" x="124" y="43" width="164" height="19" forecolor="#006699"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{criticality}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="8c4c1f4e-a5ac-4600-af3b-6a2f74b17b5f" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="62" width="124" height="20" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E3E3E3"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Notes]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="4d7b1e31-33a0-4c5b-9576-9ca9221ab2f3" mode="Opaque" x="124" y="62" width="164" height="20" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E3E3E3"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{notes}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <line>
            <reportElement uuid="9721dd86-1744-40eb-a378-87e8b00acb06" x="0" y="93" width="555" height="1"/>
        </line>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="3622cfdb-db15-4fe6-8d9c-30d6bd51a4df" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="94" width="555" height="20" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Divisions]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="17">
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="e963f52c-256f-42ce-bf06-5abeaae6532a" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="4" width="515" height="13" backcolor="#E6E6E6"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement uuid="4aa95590-464b-4759-9865-201021b8d77c" mode="Opaque" x="515" y="4" width="40" height="13" backcolor="#E6E6E6"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
            <reportElement uuid="f5f6139c-b44e-4354-8216-29550ebbcdd0" x="0" y="4" width="100" height="13"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band/>
</summary>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I managed to access the list elements by using the following variable in the jasper report

```
 $F{divisions.[0].name}
 $F{divisions.[1].name}
```

The problem is now that this is not really usable in a real report as I don't know how many elements are in the list.

Is there a way to iterate through the list elements in a jasper report?

Comment: Can you post the *jrxml* file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using by

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{data}.get(0) != null]]></printWhenExpression>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data}.get(0).name]]></textFieldExpression>
```

for divisions:

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{data}.get(0).divisions != null && $F{data}.get(0).divisions.get(0) != null]]></printWhenExpression>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data}.get(0).divisions.get(0).name]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Comment: Hmm, it's not really working.
If I add the following I get an error:

     <textField>
    <reportElement uuid="d5600e4f-7931-461e-89c3-348b16fb37fb" x="24" y="114" width="196" height="20"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{divisions}.get(0).name]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>

Adding the printWhenExpression doesn't work either. Were do I have to put that exactly?